# Deadlock using Spring. Where is the Bean?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, transactions

In an inherited setup (previously written code), I have:

- MySQL 5.0
- Spring 3.1.2
- Java 1.6

I'm getting the following:

*Error Code: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction*

... whenever I run a simple SELECT to obtain one field from one (sometimes 2) rows. I can even reproduce this when running the select in MySqlAdmin.

The SQL operation is done in a Java class that's being created, has the method for the select called, then the object goes out of scope. This class is a *NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport*.

It turns out that a different instance of the same class is performing an update on the same table.

In order to find out more about the transaction management, hopefully stop this deadlock, and after looking at Spring docs, I looked for a transaction management in the XML and found nothing.

Also, some of the "DAO" classes have a bean associated with it:

```
<bean id="fooDao" class="com.messmo.library.dao.FooDaoJdbc">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

... but the aforementioned class has no bean.

Spring has some docs on transaction management, which I've read, but I'm not sure what the default transaction handling is and if it could be related to this issue.

Comment: You need to find another context XML that defines `dataSource` and `transactionManager` beans. They can reside in a different module/project

Comment: It's possible to define a DataSource as a bean without using Spring transaction management.  It's also possible to use Spring TX management without explicitly declaring a bean named transactionManager.  For example, `<tx:annotation-driven/>` implicitly creates a bean by that name.  Set the logging for org.springframework.transaction to DEBUG and check for output.

Comment: @hoaz:There is an id="dataSource" bean a file called application-beans.xml. But there is no transactionManager bean.

The dataSource bean defines this property:
<property name="defaultTargetDataSource" ref="mysql_read" />

Along with a map of entries:
<entry key="DEFAULT_R" value-ref="mysql_read" />
<entry key="DEFAULT_RW" value-ref="mysql_readWrite" />

Comment: @JohnR : I see neither transactionManger beans nor annotations as you mentioned. Could the use of C3PO be handling some of the transactions?

Comment: I doubt that c3p0 is part of the problem.  It just hands out  connections to callers that ask and allows callers to return connections back to the pool.  If a caller returns a connection that is not in autoCommit mode and has not been committed, by default c3p0 will roll the transaction back.  You can [configure this behavior](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_unresolved).

Comment: Have you considered a tool like [jdbcdslog] (https://code.google.com/p/jdbcdslog/) to log the stack trace of each SQL call?  I'd do that and review the stack traces for anything that could be managing transactions.